# Rails - redirect_to not really redirecting - showing 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

on my site, I'm checking to see if the user has been authenticated. I have in my controller the following..

```
def index
  login_required
  @profile = current_user.profile  ### line 9
  ..
```

Then in my application_controller, I have the definition of the login_required method..

```
def login_required
  unless current_user
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Please login first"
  end
end
```

Even though my log shows me that the redirection to root is happening, it's still not really taking me to the root path, and rather takes me back to my controller->index 
and errors out on the line "@profile = current_user.profile". here's the log..

```
Started GET "/meetings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-05 12:18:12 -0800
  Processing by xyzController#index as HTML
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/xyz_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

Why am I not being redirected to the root path (which is my home page) even though it's saying that it's redirecting? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing keeps happening after `redirect_to` - there's no implicit `return`.  The band-aid fix is to add a `return` in your index action depending on the result of `login_required`, but the better way is to use a [filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) in your controller.

Comment: Thanks..yeah, i'll probably have to go with a before_filter. THanks.